# sorting of an Iqueryable

Tags: linq-to-sql, iqueryable

I have an IQueryable with duplicate entries and I want to sort this IQueryable by the count of occurrences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
from e in myQueryable
group e by e.Something into g
order by g.Count()
select g  //Or, g.First()
```

Comment: is there anyway to get the maximum occurring element first than the least.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
list
    .GroupBy(x => x.ID)
    .Select(x => new {Obj = x.First(), Count = x.Count()})
    .OrderBy(x => x.Count)
    .Select(x => x.Obj);
```

I like SLaks' solution more, though.

```
list
    .GroupBy(x => x.ID)             
    .OrderBy(x => x.Count())
    .Select(x => x.First());
```

Comment: I do not see a problem here, anyways fixed :).

Comment: I did not mean to imply that there was a problem.